# Mongo DB Query in Arraylist

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist

In my Java Play framework application, I want to store the ArrayList values in mongoDB.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5832f29bd4c6721e4e8ba4a7"),
    "_class" : "com.netas.innovation.entity.Idea",
    "title" : "fsaf",
    "desc" : "adgg",
    "keyWords" : "dgds",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-11-21T13:11:55.823Z"),
    "checkbox1" : false,
    "checkbox2" : false,
    "checkbox3" : false,
    "scopeOfIdea" : "Herkes",
    "template" : false,
    "creatorUser" : {
        "$ref" : "user",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5832f27dd4c6721e4e8ba4a5")
    },
    "owners" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "user",
            "$id" : ObjectId("5832f27dd4c6721e4e8ba4a5")
        }
    ],
    "answer" : {
        "$ref" : "answer",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5832f29bd4c6721e4e8ba4a6")
    },
    "fileList" : []
}
```

i  want to search in owners.

My query doesnt work

```
if(owners != null && !owners.isEmpty()) {

           for(int i=0; i<owners.size(); i++) {
              criteriaList.add(new **Criteria().elemMatch(Criteria.where("owners.$id").is(owners.get(i).getId())));**
            }
        }
```

How can i fix? 
i can search by owners.
owners can be two people or three

Thanks for answers

Comment: Please add more details such as your schema and your expected output, it will be helping in the understanding the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
"owners" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "user(list)",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5832ecdb0deb78cc88392c83")
    }
```

$ref :  ozgurk,volkany ...

Answer (score 0):

http://prntscr.com/ddz3c9  this example for output... title desc vs vsdate and owners

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mongodb expert but, I guess you should do somethink like:

```
List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
...
List idList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < owners.size(); i++) {
     idList.add(owners.get(i).getId());
}
criteriaList.add(new Criteria().where("owners.$id").in(idList));
...
```

If you add each owner=owners.get(i).getId() criteria to the list one by one and finally combine all criterias with AND operation you will not get your desired output.

I guess you use Spring data. I tried to write following mongodb query:

```
db.getCollection('idea').find(
    {
           "owners.$id": {
               "$in" : [
                     ObjectId("58451c5f13c97bdde9950641"),
                     ObjectId("28451c5f13c97bdde9950642")
               ]
           }
    }
)
```